# Facing issue in creating category with category url key and name as "products" in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

If i create a new category in Magento-1.9 version with "category url key" and "category name" as "**products**", then i'm facing lot of issues in "products" category like

1. Automatically creating new "filter" option for each time re-sizing the browser to check the responsive.
2. Creating this filter or refined search tab in top and above items.
3. Options in the filter or refined search is also not working in this page.

Getting same issues in all browsers and in different machines

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I have created a category with  "category url key" and "category name" as "products" in fresh magento backend. I have not altered any codings.